# Retain Row Formatting When Sorting

Tags: google-sheets, formatting, sorting

After performing a sort, the row's formatting doesn't retain it's row height and other custom format, and the row the data was in previously will retain the prior height/format instead of becoming the default. The cells that had strike throughs will also keep it unless I manually remove it. This is an endless reformatting and data correction issue to fix over and over. How do you perform a sort function or a copy/paste/move without this happening?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide an example of your data before and after with the desired result. The kind of solution will depend on the problem space